# Why optimize feature does'nt appear for next two println?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "UNI:5";
        String str2 = "UNI:" + 5;
        String str3 = "UNI:" + str1.length();
        System.out.println(str1 == str2);
        System.out.println(str1 == str3);
        System.out.println(str1 == new String(str1));
    }
```

and we get :

true

false

flase

 it should be something like "false flase false" !

Comment: Why do you think they should all be false?

Comment: Because as Johan said : "Remember that == compares by reference" !! so I thought it should print false :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str1 = "UNI:5";
String str2 = "UNI:" + 5;
```

These strings are exactly the same at compile time (no unknown variables involved) thus they will be treated as the same value in the string pool.

Since `==` checks for their references, it will return true because they point to the same entry.

if you would introduce a randomized feature, it will return `false` because it cannot be guaranteed that these will be the same

```
String str1 = "UNI:5";
String str2 = "UNI:" + getSomething();

private int getSomething() {
   return new Random().nextDouble() > 0.5 ? 1 : 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that == compares by reference. Since the two first strings are equal, the compiler will optimize them to the same instance.

To properly compare strings, use the `equals()` method.